# Counterexamples to implications of mean value theorem without completeness

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, real-numbers, rational-numbers, monotone-functions

By using the mean value theorem (for which we require completeness) we can show for a function $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable on $(a,b)$ that
$$f \;\text{monotone increasing}\iff \forall x\in (a,b)\colon f'(x)\ge 0.$$
Now, differentiation does not require completeness. Limits can be defined by only using the rationals, thus we can define the derivative for a function only defined on $[a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Then we can easily find counterexamples to the mean value theorem by choosing a differentiable function $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(a)=f(b)$ whose only maximum lies in an irrational point and then considering the rational function $f\mid_{[a,b]\,\cap\, \mathbb{Q}}$.

My question is now: Is there a counterexample to the above statement, where the implication from the RHS to the LHS is incorrect? A function on the rationals or some "rational interval", which is not monotone, but differentiable everywhere with positive derivative?

Comment: Note that there's no guarantee that your rational-valued function on the rationals has rational-valued derivative. Other than that issue, I think if $f'$ exists and is positive on a dense set then $f$ is strictly increasing, but I am not sure about a proof. (Note that the situation is rather different with your Rolle's violation scenario because the sign change in the derivative is still there in that situation, whereas there is no sign change in the situation of the question.)

Comment: True, that is an extra condition I'd need to impose on the definition of "rational derivative". I feel confident that it is still possible to define a counterexample to the mean value theorem with my method, but it needs a bit of work.

Comment: I stand corrected...it actually makes a lot of sense that the trick is to break continuity, not just differentiability. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is totally disconnected, you can have two "nice" functions meet up at an irrational point to form a continuous function at all rational points without the result being continuous at the "joint".

Comment: Yup, that's what I figured with those counterexamples. Probably the reason why I didn't feel fully satisfied yet. Then again, they did answer the question I posed, so I must recognise and accept their answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(q)=\frac q2$ when $q^2 < 2$ and $f(q)=q-2$ for $q^2 \ge 2$ with $q \in \mathbb Q$

then $f'(q) = \frac12$ or $1$ for all $q \in \mathbb Q$ but $f(q)$ is not an increasing function: $f(1)=\frac12$ while $f(2)=0$

Comment: I love these types of counter-examples 

Comment: Great counterexample and it certainly does answer the question I posed. Not yet fully satisfied, but that's more a me problem, haha.

Comment: Any chance of an example that extends to a continuous function on $[a,b]$?

Comment: @Ian This is a continuous function on the rationals - if it was discontinuous then it could not have a derivative at all rational numbers.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But it doesn't extend to a continuous function on $[a,b]$: you achieved the non-monotonicity by using a jump. I am asking whether this is essential or not.