# Counterexample to implications of mean value theorem over the rationals that can be extended to a differentiable function on the reals

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, real-numbers, rational-numbers, monotone-functions

This is a follow-up question to a [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187068/counterexamples-to-implications-of-mean-value-theorem-without-completeness). The previous one was answered (in fact it was a duplicate), but I still didn't feel like my inquiry was over.

The original question was about the mean value theorem on a space which is not complete, in this case $\mathbb{Q}$. We can easily find a function $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ which doesn't satisfy the mean value theorem by choosing a function with $f(a)=f(b),a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ and the only maximum or minimum $x_m\in (a,b)\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$.

My question now was: Is there a function $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$, differentiable everywhere (on $\mathbb{Q}$) with a nonnegative derivative $f'(x)\ge 0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, but which is not monotone increasing.

It turns out that finding a such a function is a bit more difficult, but conceptually not much different - we simply take a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that has a jump discontinuity at some irrational point but is constant everywhere else, then take its restriction $f\mid_{\mathbb{Q}}$.

At this point I wasn't satisfied, because it felt pathological to force a function into discontinuity in its (mostly continuous) extension to the reals. I started wondering whether I could construct a function that could be continuously extended to the reals and maybe even be differentiable everywhere.

Here I figured that, if it was differentiable everywhere, the derivative could not be continuous, since the derivative was nonnegative on a dense subset, so would have to be nonnegative everywhere. I also noticed that as soon as $f'(x)<0$ for some irrational $x\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, the derivative would have to take every value between $f'(x)$ and $0$ between $x$ and any rational point $p/q$ by the [theorem of Darboux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29), which states that even non continuous derivatives satisfy the intermediate value theorem.

This feels impossible, but I don't know. So I approached the idea from a different angle. How about constructing the derivative and then taking its primitive?

My question now became: Is there a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(p/q)=0$ for every rational $p/q$ but $f(x)<0$ for some irrational $x$? This in itself can easily be constructed, but is it still possible if we force the regularity condition that $f$ is integrable and the continuous $F\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t$ is differentiable everywhere with derivative $F'=f$ or at least $F'(y)=f(y)<0$ for some irrational $y$? Or maybe that $f$ satisfies the intermediate value theorem?

If you have input or an answer to any of my question, I'd much appreciate the ideas. I myself am stuck here. The idea seems impossible, but I am still missing the argument as to why. Maybe someone here can help. Cheers!

Edit: José Carlos Santos reply showed that my previous conditions on $f$ would not be enough to give a primitive that is not monotone increasing. So I needed to impose more conditions.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for but the [Minkowski question mark function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function) might be of interest. It is a continuous bijection $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, and restricts to a function $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$ that is differentiable with derivative $0$ at every rational.

Comment: Wow. What a function. It certainly is of interest. Since it is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$, its derivative has to be $\ge 0$. But then $-?$ would satisfy all the conditions of my first question and its derivative would have to satisfy the second condition. I don't know enough about this function, but what does it's derivative do on irrational inputs?

Comment: It's not differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb R$. The sources I can immediately find are a bit vague about its derivative outside $\mathbb Q$; I get the impression it is not fully understood exactly _which_ irrationals it is differentiable at.

Comment: I see. This is unfortunate, because it seemed like a really good candidate. At least it is an example of a function which is strictly increasing, even though its derivative is zero everywhere on the rationals, and is still continuously extendable to the reals. Maybe differentiability everywhere is just too much to hope for. But then, why not, is there a way to prove that it's impossible?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative describes a related construction -- though this time without the nice property of restricting to $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I was under the impression that you were looking for a function over the rationals with certain properties, and that the extension to the reals was merely a means to an end. Does it really matter whether the real function is differentiable, as long as the function over the rationals is?

Comment: @Troposphere I am noticing that real numbers are much weirder than I thought possible, even though I was prepared to accept a lot of weirdness after finding out about Conway's base 13 function... Thanks anyway. This might actually lead to a solution.

Comment: @DavidK You're right, this was a means to an end. I am pretty sure that Minkowski's question-mark function satisfies my original request. I was just wondering whether it is still possible via the other means, because, to be honest, this is quite fascinating.

Comment: Note that the "no jumps" property of the question mark function can be expressed without leaving $\mathbb Q$ by observing that it is _uniformly continuous_.

Answer (score 1):

Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\ne\sqrt2\\-1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$If you define $F\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ by $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$, then $F$ is differentiable everywhere, since it is the null function.

Comment: Yup, you're right. I didn't consider this. Apparently my condition wasn't enough, so I might have to impose the extra condition from before as well that between the irrational point $x$ where $f(x)<0$ and any other rational point the function $f$ has to attain every value between $f(x)$ and $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I'm not sure anymore that this answer is even relevant to the question, let alone helpful. I would have deleted it already except for the value of the comments. I may delete it anyway eventually.

---

There is a basic conceptual problem with what you are trying to do.
You apparently know that there are far more irrational numbers than rational numbers,
which is a correct understanding.
But you have a misconception that it is possible to find several irrational numbers between one rational number and the "next" one.

The rational numbers are dense in the reals.
If you take any two real numbers $x,$ $y$ such that $x<y,$ $f(x)< 0,$ and $f(y)<0$, there is some rational number $p/q$ such that $x < p/q < y.$

Comment: Can you elaborate which part leads you to the assumption of a missconception? I would like to change that part then. I am very well aware that there are no next rational numbers (unless of course we choose an order, which is superfluous here) and also that the rationals are dense as well as what that means. If I have a value $f(x)<0$ then $f$ needs to take every value between $f(x)$ and $0$ between $x$ and any rational $p/q$. Meaning that any value has to be taken infinitely many times, because I can always find a rational between $x$ and $y$. But I don't see why this should be impossible?

Comment: It seemed that you were trying to squeeze an integrable interval of the real function between two irrational numbers. On the other hand, if you negate the Minkowski question mark function, perhaps you get what you really want.